# Decltype of a container from an argument of a function

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I'm trying to deduct the type of the stl container inside a function from the function's argument and it doesn't compile:

```
auto battery_capacity( const vector<double>& v) -> decltype(v)::value_type {
  decltype(v)::value_type b=0;
  return b;
}
```

error:

```
main.cpp:10:52: error: 'decltype(v)' (aka 'const vector<double> &') is not a class, namespace, or scoped
      enumeration
auto battery_capacity( const vector<double>& v) -> decltype(v)::value_type {
                                                   ^
main.cpp:11:3: error: 'decltype(v)' (aka 'const vector<double> &') is not a class, namespace, or scoped enumeration
  decltype(v)::value_type b=0;
```

however this compiles:

```
double battery_capacity( const vector<double>& v) {
  vector<double> s=v;
  decltype(s)::value_type b=0;
  return b;
}
```

**Update (1)**

Addition for when using templates based on Kerrek's answer:

```
template <typename T>
auto battery_capacity( const T& v) -> typename std::remove_reference<decltype(v)>::type::value_type {
  typename std::remove_reference<decltype(v)>::type::value_type b=0;
  return b;
}
```

Comment: There's a difference between `decltype(s)` and `decltype((s))`...

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: After the update, I would *seriously* just write `template <typename T> typename T::value_type battery_capacity(T const & v) { return { 0 }; }`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you really really must force the use of `decltype` into this very simple code (and I'd call that misguided), then it's like this:

```
auto battery_capacity(const vector<double> & v) -> std::remove_reference<decltype(v)>::type::value_type
{
    std::remove_reference<decltype(v)>::type::value_type b = 0;
    return b;
}
```

If you're unsure why you need to write this, you *really* don't want to be using `decltype` at all. It's a very specialized tool for a very specialized kind of generic library writing, not for common household use.

Of course the simpler answer is just to write `double battery_capacity(...)`, since you know the type already! (If you don't actually know the type, then you didn't ask the right question, and your question doesn't reflect your actual problem.)

In C++14, you can be a little shorter:

```
auto battery_capacity(const vector<double> & v)
{
    return std::remove_reference_t<decltype(v)>::value_type { 0 };
}
```

Comment: 1. templates. 2. it's redundant to write the type multiple times, the program should deduct it like in c++14. it's useful with snippets

Comment: @kirill_igum: 1) that's a totally different problem, and your question is outright misleading. Please ask the question that you care about, not some other, unrelated question. That wastes everyone's time. 2) That depends.

Comment: regarding (1), the question is general I didn't mention templates or not but your answer works for both. I updated the question with the case for the templates. Thank you for the critique. I that hope now it's better.